# Excel Analysis Prompt as cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, prompt, analysis

I've recently started using Excel Analysis and I'm trying to revamp some existing sheets that I've inherited. Is there a way for the prompts to accept a value from a cell reference?

For example, currently we have a facility number which gets populated as a prompt - can I have the facility number be referenced somewhere on the sheet itself so that instead of hard coding it into a prompt, the prompt pulls its designated value from a designated location on the sheet?

I have the value that I want to feed the prompt entered into cell A31 - and would love to be able to point the prompt to =A31. So that the user won't have to manually change the prompt when running an analysis for a different facility.

Comment: More details would be helpful. Assuming you mean the Analysis ToolPak add-in. what specific functionality are you using? Are you using the Analysis VBA functions?

Comment: Yes - using the Analysis ToolPak add-in within Excel. This pulls queries from SAP which take in certain prompts from the Analysis-Prompts menu. I was wondering if there is a way to pass the prompt value as a cell reference rather than having to enter it directly into the prompt.

Comment: Perhaps if you use the Analysis VBA functions. Otherwise kinda hard to say.